# Button width is halved on each click Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/creating-second-shop-qa?playlist=17111
I've followed the tutorial above. On the link above the code is visible.
The only difference is the line in ShopScrollList listed below.

Old:

```
newButton.transform.SetParent(contentPanel);
```

New:

```
newButton.transform.SetParent(contentPanel, false);
```

My problem is that when I click a button in either list both lists buttons become halved in width. This occurs every time I click a button.

Comment: Is the scale of the parent you are setting (contentPanel) 0.5 (or another value that isn't 1 )? since you are adding it as a child object it will set its own `transform.localScale` relative to the parent

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I had to set `worldPositionStays` to false on these two lines in `SimpleObjectPool.cs`.

```
spawnedGameObject.transform.SetParent(null, false);

toReturn.transform.SetParent(transform, false);
```